# image resolution for banner and logo

Tags: android, ios, image, screen, tablet

I have a problem with image size and resolution on my app I need to upload an image then I want to resize it to all screen, which is the best image size and width/height for banner and logo and I need a good tool that resizes image?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to remake the logo in a vector format, this relies on positions rather than individual pixels.

In other words no matter how big you make the image, it will always be crisp and sharp.

If I remember to back when I dabbled in Android development I seem to remember android making different sized versions of the logo and banner... Therefore what I would do is create the logo in a vector program such as `Inkscape` or `Adobe Illustrator`, and exporting it as a high quality png, this way if you need to resize it in the future, you just export it at a different size and you're good to go.